# ActionBar throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I couldnt figure out this one. I am customizing my ActionBar (and yes my App is for 3.0+) The code runs fine on Device(using Motorola xoom ,if it matters) .But when i run this on Emulator it throws NPE.This is my code for ActionBar

```
/**
 * Customizes Action bar sets background color and assigns a layout to it
 */
private void customActionBar() {
    Log.v(TAG, "customizing ActionBar Entry");
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    Log.v(TAG, "customizing ActionBar : "+actionBar.toString());
            //This is where i get NPE
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor(Constants.COLOR)));
    Log.v(TAG, "customizing ActionBar -Background color : ");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action, null);
    // lay.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
    // android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    // android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    Log.v(TAG, "customizing ActionBar Exit");
}
```

EDIT : logcat

```
V/>>> FullPdfViewerActivity(438): customizing ActionBar Entry
D/AndroidRuntime(438): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(438): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
E/AndroidRuntime(438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity                                 
ComponentInfo{com.test.android.tester/com.test.android.tester.core.AwesomePagerActivity}:          java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(438): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.test.android.tester.core.AwesomePagerActivity.customActionBar(AwesomePagerActivity.java:227)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.test.android.tester.core.AwesomePagerActivity.onCreate(AwesomePagerActivity.java:187)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
E/AndroidRuntime(438):  ... 11 more
```

I call this from my onCreate() .I am worried if it will work for other devices??

TIA

Comment: Can you please provide logcat ?

Comment: earlier it was setBackgroundDrawable .But when I used toString() its showing NPE.Its there in comment

Comment: What does Constants.COLOR look like?

Comment: its a hex value for color like "#c3c3c3" and is a string.But I get NPE  for actionBar.toString()

Comment: guys you can try this on your emulator for 3.0...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, that `getActionBar()` returns null. I saw this behavior when `getActionBar()` was called before `setContentView()` of activity, but only on Android 3.0 and 3.1, on Android 3.2 order does not matter. 
Try to call `setContentView` before customizing action bar

Comment: You made my day...
but still havent understood hw does it works for device.Isnt there something called platform independence...
anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in some circumstances, you may need to do any calls in onActivityCreated as the view may not be ready.